# How can I make it so the text is in the center of the cell instead of the space?

Tags: html

So I'm trying to code this email in html and am having problem with this one part. (No CSS on this one)

I have a table. In one cell, I want an image aligned left then the text centered in the same cell.
THEN, the next cell down, I want the image to be aligned right then the text centered.

The problem is, when I center those texted, they are not in the same line vertically. They are sort-of off-set.

How can I make it so the text is in the center of the cell instead of the space?

Here is an example of my html code right now.

```
<tr>
<td>
<img src="pic.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" align="left" />
<p style="vertical-align: middle;" align="center"> Text</p>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<img src="pic.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" align="right" />
<p style="align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> Text</p>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding an HTML email (like it's 1999) can be understandably annoying. In the snippet below I've turned each row into 3 cells (the image cell set to the width of the image, the centered text, and an empty cell set to the width again of the image [and then the reverse for the next row]):

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
  <td width="50">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" width="50px" height="50px" align="left" />
  </td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <p style="text-align: center">Text</p>
  </td>
  <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>  
  <td width="50">&nbsp;</td>
  <td valign="middle">
    <p style="text-align: center">Text</p>
  </td>
  <td width="50">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" width="50px" height="50px" align="right" />
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think it does what you were asking but whether it will work in your specific case I don't know.